# In Websphere Commerce 7, how do I remove the language and store name from an SEO url the correct way?

Tags: java, url, seo, websphere, websphere-7

Currently the client I'm working for is making use of the SEO Friendly urls outlined here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZLC2_8.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.seositemap.doc/concepts/csdSEOURLconstruction.htm

However, they would like to have `/en/clientstorename` removed from all urls.  For example, when a user navigates to www.clientwebsite.com, the url automatically switches over to www.clientwebsite.com/en/clientstorename.  I would like to remove the `/en/clientstorename` from the url, and all other urls on the site.

The client has also informed me that IHS changes are not a possible solution to this problem.

So, to my knowledge, that leaves me with the single option of directly removing the /LanguageToken/StoreToken:CatalogToken parts from all entries in each SEOURLPatterns xml file.  That is to say, my thinking was make this change throughout all SEOURLPatterns xml files in the workspace.  **(Note the commented out existing line and my uncommented modified line)**

```
<seourl:seoUrlPatternDef name="PersonalizedProductURLPIPPage">
<!--<seourl:seoUrlPattern viewName="ThirdPartyVendorProductsDisplayView">/LanguageToken/StoreToken:CatalogToken/ProductToken/PCPToken/BeginIndexToken/ioZoneToken</seourl:seoUrlPattern>-->
    <seourl:seoUrlPattern viewName="ThirdPartyVendorProductsDisplayView">/ProductToken/PCPToken/BeginIndexToken/ioZoneToken</seourl:seoUrlPattern> 
    <seourl:urlToParamMapping>
        <seourl:mapping name="langId" value="?LanguageToken?"/>
        <seourl:mapping name="storeId" value="?StoreToken?"/>
        <seourl:mapping name="catalogId" value="?CatalogToken?"/>
        <seourl:mapping name="productId" value="?ProductToken?"/>
        <seourl:mapping name="plchldr" value="?PCPToken?"/>
        <seourl:mapping name="mfname" value="?BeginIndexToken?" />
        <seourl:mapping name="styleId" value="?ioZoneToken?" />
        <seourl:mapping name="errorViewName" value="ProductDisplayErrorView"/>
    </seourl:urlToParamMapping>
    <seourl:paramToUrlMapping>
        <seourl:mapping name="LanguageToken" value="?langId?" defaultValue="-1"/>
        <seourl:mapping name="StoreToken" value="?storeId?"/>
        <seourl:mapping name="CatalogToken" value="?catalogId?"/>
        <seourl:mapping name="ProductToken" value="?productId?"/>
        <seourl:mapping name="PCPToken" value="?plchldr?"/>
        <seourl:mapping name="BeginIndexToken" value="?mfname?"/>
        <seourl:mapping name="ioZoneToken" value="?styleId?"/>
    </seourl:paramToUrlMapping>
    <seourl:usageDef>
        <seourl:usage device="browser">
            <seourl:target>CatalogEntry</seourl:target>
        </seourl:usage>
    </seourl:usageDef>
</seourl:seoUrlPatternDef>
```

When I do this, I do see that the URLs generated are now leaving out the `/en/clientstorename`, however every page just shows a generic error message, and even turning the logging up all the way to `*=all` shows nothing in the console.

I'm kind of stuck here and not sure how to proceed.  Is there a class somewhere that I can hijack in order to get these parts of the SEO urls removed?  When I remove the /en/clientstorename using the SEOURLPatterns.xml files, there are undocumented exceptions being thrown and I'm unsure how to proceed down that route.

I have also tried to intercept and remove the /en/clientstorename from the URL inside of the SEOURLMapper class, but my testing with this didn't actually affect the URL displayed in the browser.

What is the best way of removing this /en/clientstorename from each url on my client's site without affecting the functionality of the site itself.

Comment: question: Are you looking for a solution where URLs just end up getting redirected to an SEO-friendly canonical URL or a solution where the URLs that are generated on the webpages themselves are the SEO-friendly canonical URLs?

Comment: did you try: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.seositemap.doc/concepts/csdSEOpatternfiles.htm

Comment: also here is a great resource: https://www.scribd.com/document/281070301/searchengineoptimizationseo-130820015428-phpapp02

Comment: enable more detailed logging and tracing in your WebSphere Application Server

Comment: Why the Java tag? Also the link you shared points to a page that only says this product is no longer supported.

Answer (score -1):

In WebSphere Commerce 7, managing SEO URLs involves configuring the URL patterns and settings in the WebSphere Commerce Management Center. To remove the language and store name from an SEO URL, you'll typically need to adjust the URL patterns and settings. Here's a general guide on how to achieve this:

```
Access the Management Center:
    Log in to the WebSphere Commerce Management Center.

Navigate to SEO Configuration:
    In the Management Center, go to the "Merchandising" tab.
    Under "Search Engine Optimization (SEO)," select "SEO Configuration."

Modify URL Patterns:
    Find the section that allows you to configure SEO URL patterns.
    Look for patterns related to language and store name in URLs.
    Modify the URL patterns to exclude the language and store name. You might need to use a pattern like /{category}/{product} without including language or store name placeholders.

Update Store URL Settings:
    Go to "Stores" in the Management Center.
    Select your store and navigate to the "Store URL and SEO" section.
    Check for any settings related to including language or store name in URLs and disable them.

Rebuild and Publish:
    After making changes, rebuild and publish your store to apply the new URL configurations.
    This process ensures that the changes take effect on the live site.

Test URLs:
    After making changes and publishing, test the URLs to ensure that language and store name are no longer included.
```